# Authentication for git-bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying to store code on bitbucket using Git,but i got authentication problem.
Here i entered password of bitbucket login,but its give an 
fatal:Authentication failed,so which password can i enter for this problem.

```
git push -u origin master

Password for 'https://prashant_123@bitbucket.org':
```

fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://prashant_123@bitbucket.org/prashant_123/test.git/'

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using the internet.

Comment: it seems the user account `prashant_123` does not exist? have you created a user account and a repo named `test` on bitbucket?

Comment: Close reason was due to the question containing a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless this is some kind of outage (which isn't supported by the [Bitbucket status page](http://status.bitbucket.org/)), this is likely the result of an incorrect url,

- either because there is no account `prashant_123` (or `prashant123`)
- or because there is one, but with a different case (`Prashant_123`)

The same would go for the repo (no `test` repo, or '`Test`', but with a different case).